# Apache Airflow: monitor data pipelines not triggered by airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, azure-functions, airflow

I read some articles about Airflow 101. AFAIK, Airflow's orchestration is for data pipelines triggered by Airflow.

In my situation, I have some data pipelines running on serverless solutions (e.g. GCP cloud function, Azure function app, AWS lambda, VM crontab ... etc.)

How can I monitor these data pipelines without changing the pipeline triggers? Or, in another way, if triggered by Airflow is a 'must'. What would be the better way to minimize the modification of existing data pipelines?

I ask this question because some data pipelines can not be triggered easily like HTTP (e.g. event trigger in each cloud service. Like GCP cloud function with pubsub trigger, Azure function with queue\blob ... trigger)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in prior.

Comment: Have you checked this link for [triggering Dags with Cloud Functions?](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf)

Comment: This article is talking about "trigger a DAG in airflow programmatically, not trigger by airflow itself", right?

Comment: Apache airflow is orchestration tool, if you want to put in Airflow all of this functionless tools/services it would be perfect, then you can monitor, observe by airflow plugged in one observability tool, like grafana for example.
If you put all this tasks in airflow it would be easily to check error msg inside tasks logs or status of each task in airflow dags. That's the main points when you use any orchestration data tool

Comment: @DiegoLopes thanks. So, if I want to use airflow, I should try my best to make all pipelines triggered by airflow. Then airflow can take care all dirty works for me. If I need advanced monitoring features, I can do this with grafana. Am I understand you correctly?

Comment: yes, that's it @hanshih